# in if rewards[current_state, j]>0: IndexError: index 12 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 12

Tags: python

```
What am i doing wrong here?

rewards = np.array([[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                    [1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                    [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
                    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
                    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
                    [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
                    [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
                    [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
                    [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
                    [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],
                    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1],
                    [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0]])

#Building Q

Q = np.array(np.zeros([12,12]))

for i in range(1000):<p>
    current_state = random.randint(0,12)<p>
    playable_actions = []<p>
    for j in range(11):<p>
        if rewards[current_state, j]>0:<p>
            playable_actions.append(j)<p>
    next_state = random.choice(playable_actions)<p>
```

Gives the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/AI for Business/warehouse_flow.py", line 47, in 
    if rewards[current_state, j]>0:
IndexError: index 12 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 12

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in `numpy.randint`, the `random.randint(low, high)` you are using produces an `int` that is lower than or equal to `high`, which means it can be 12. And since `numpy` arrays are 0-based, their range is 0 to 11. So when `current_state` gets 12, the command `rewards[current_state, j]` gives a non-existing index.

Either use `numpy.random.randint(0, 12)` or change it to `random.randint(0, 11)`

Answer (score 0):

random.randint(0,12) can also return 12. So write this-

```
random.randint(0,11)
```